# Unfollowing deleted answer fails with irrelevant pop-up message on voting

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, follow-posts

I am trying to **unfollow** [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62018527/delay-in-drawing-cursor-position-with-sharpgl/62064660#62064660), but it proves impossible; instead, I get a pop-up message that

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on

The behavior is the same, when trying to unfollow either from the post page or from the (new) "Following" section of my profile.

Comment: Same [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question) on Meta.